# if (LV.Items.Count() == 0), else statement not working when items appear in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a student enrolment wizard that they go through every year that uses the `MultiView` control and I have multiple `View` Controls within it. An example of one `View` control can be seen below;

```
<asp:View ID="address_view" runat="server">
    <h1>Address:</h1>
<asp:Button ID="add_new_address" CssClass="blue" runat="server" Text="Add New Address" OnClick="add_new_address_Click" />
<div id="add_address_div" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="address_dropdown_insert" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Home">Home Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Term">Term Time Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mail">Mail Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Business">Business Address</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList><br />
            Address 1:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
            Address 2:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
            Town/City:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
            County:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
            PostCode:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" OnClick="insert_address_button_Click" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="Button4" OnClick="cancel_address_button_Click" /><br />
</div>
    <asp:ListView ID="address_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="user_address" DataKeyNames="address_id">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            // code here
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <br />
            <p>There are currently no addresses found, please click the button above to add a new address.</p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            //code here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            //code here
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

<br />
    <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="address_next" runat="server" Text="Next" />
</asp:View>
```

I have the following C# on `PageLoad` so that when there is no data in the `address_list` ListView the `address_next` button is not enabled and when there is data in the ListView the button should be enabled.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    if (address_list.Items.Count() == 0)
    {
        address_next.Enabled = false;
        feedbacktest.Text = "No Data";
    }
    else
    {
        address_next.Enabled = true;
        feedbacktest.Text = "Data";
    }
```

When I load the website and there is data in the ListView like the image below, the `feebacktest` Label displays "No Data" so I am unable to click the `address_next` button. I would like it so that if there is data in the ListView that the button becomes enabled.

I'm fairly new to C# so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

## EDIT

This is how I bind a new address in C#

```
protected void insert_address_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userid = Session["user_id"].ToString();
        string addtype = address_dropdown_insert.SelectedValue;
        string add1 = address_1TextBox.Text;
        string add2 = address_2TextBox.Text;
        string town = town_cityTextBox.Text;
        string county = countyTextBox.Text;
        string pcode = postcodeTextBox.Text;
        string country = countryTextBox.Text;

        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        String query = "INSERT INTO address (user_id, address_type, address_1, address_2, town_city, county, postcode, country) VALUES (@user_id, @address_type, @address_1, @address_2, @town_city, @county, @postcode, @country)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", userid);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_type", addtype);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_1", add1);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_2", add2);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@town_city", town);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@county", county);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", pcode);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();

        user_address.DataBind();
        address_list.DataBind();
        add_new_address.Visible = true;
        address_list.Visible = true;

        if (address_list.Items.Count() == 0)
        {
            address_next.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            address_next.Enabled = true;
        }
```

### ANSWER

I figured out my issue, I just needed to add the following code which I had in my insert.

```
protected void year_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    user_address.DataBind();
    address_list.DataBind();
    if (address_list.Items.Count() == 0)
    {
        address_next.Enabled = false;
        feedbacktest.Text = "No Data";
    }
    else
    {
        address_next.Enabled = true;
        feedbacktest.Text = "Data";
    }
}
```

Comment: How to bind address_list ?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I have edited my answer to reflect how I do this. I use the same code from page load in this `protected void` and it works in this case, but just not on page load.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I was able to figure out my problem, I think your question helped me find the answer, thank you.